# X11 monitor in lightdm displays differently than xinit

Tags: x11, antialiasing, xserver

I'm running 2 X-servers on my ubuntu machine.

The first X-server is started with lightdm, and the font's shown look the way I want them to (first screenshot).

The 2nd is an X-server started with xinit -- :1, and when I run emacs, the font's shown look skinny (I don't want that behavior).

My question is: how can I change the 2nd X-server to behave like the first. The outputs shown by xset and xrandr show no differences.. where else would I look. thanks

[image: screenshot 1 (w/anti-aliasing)]

[image: screenshot 2 (without/anti-aliasing)]